# Is it possible to to add custom fields to FeedItem object?

Tags: feeditem

Is it possible to to add custom fields to FeedItem object? Also where can I see the object and its fields (apart from documentation) inside salesforce platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot edit FeedItem.  You can't see the object itself, but you can manage settings related to Chatter such as triggers on FeedItem under Setup->Customize->Chatter.

If you're interested in seeing the properties of FeedItem I suggest checking out workbench.  The Standard and Custom Object section under Info is invaluable.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Thank you. It seems I cannot create a master detail relationship referencing FeedItem inside a custom object. I could hack by referencing an FeedItem Id though. Your answer helps!

Comment: No problem.  I've faced the same thing with wanting to link up to metadata type fields like profile, apexclass, apexpage, etc.  Hopefully some day they add options for some of these standard objects and metadata items that show as data objects.  Attachments has always been a thorn in my side too.  Many apps want to specify what type of attachment is being used.